# Using MIT license while linking with MIT and LGPLv3

Tags: mit, lgpl

I'm working on a library I would like to license under MIT license (mostly to allow its use in proprietary software).

I'm using APIs of two other libraries, one under MIT, other under LGPLv3.
I'm just linking to these, no code is reused in my project.

Can I use MIT license in this situation?

I mostly found answers and information regarding reuse of LGPL code, which must include LGPL license text, but here I'm only linking. Are there some other considerations?

Comment: Statically or dynamically linked?

Comment: @planetmaker Dynamically. I'm developing Lua binding to the LGPL library, so it's actually Lua interpreter that dynamically loads my library, and I link dynamically with the LGPL code. I'm obviously #including relevant headers. (Lua API is the MIT one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/7908/29266) to an earlier question I think my usecase permits using MIT license.

The answer is about LGPLv2.1 but as far as I know LGPLv3 is not dramatically different.
Using only library API and not modifying its code should constitute a `Combined Work` and can be distributed under any license.